# How Could I sanitize the receive data from this code

Tags: security, forms, escaping, sanitization

```
<form id="tellastory" method="post" action="">
    <label for="fullname">Full Name </label>
    <input id="fullname" name="fullname" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    <label for="title">Title </label>
    <input id="title" name="title" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/>
    <label for="title">Message </label>
    <textarea id="editor" name="editor" rows="20" cols="50"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="123456" />       
    <input id="saveForm" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php
$storyteller_user_id = "3";  //your guest user id here
//$stories_category = "3";  //your stories category id here
$key = "storyteller";

if ($_POST['form_id']=="123456") {
    $my_post = array(); 
    $my_post['post_title'] =$_POST['title'];
    $my_post['post_content'] = $_POST['editor'];
    $my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
    $my_post['post_author'] = $storyteller_user_id;
    $my_post['post_category'] = array($stories_category);
    $post_Num = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
    add_post_meta($post_Num, $key, $_POST['fullname']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Small typo you might overlook: 3rd `label` should be for `editor` not `title` again.

Answer (score 4):

Sanitization and escaping is always heavily context-dependent and I'm not an expert in this field, anyway I did some 'research' myself recently so I'll try to supply you with some general guidelines until someone with more insight will come and offer the ultimate in-depth answer (which I'll be eager to read too.)

Codex article on [Data Validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) is a good starter. I believe [esc_html()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2335) is the most used method for output.

There also seems to be a newcomer to WP escaping family in WordPress 3.1  - [esc_textarea()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2363).

WordPress is trying to make your life easier as always - so be sure to check for existing context-specific functions like [sanitize_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) or [sanitize_user()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_user).

I recommend you do some source-diving and go thru functions in [wp-includes/formatting.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/formatting.php) to learn more about various methods and how they are constructed.

There has been a similar discussion on wp-hackers recently - definitely worth reading:
[WP-HACKERS: Saving input from untrusted users](http://old.nabble.com/Saving-input-from-untrusted-users-td30502553.html). I will dare to quote Andrew Nacin's input on this one:

> Generalizing here: sanitization should
>   be done on save, and escaping on 
>   display.
>
> So you'll want to run **kses**,
>   **absint**, **esc_url_raw**, **sanitize_text_field**, what  have you, on save. Then, use **esc_url**,
>   **esc_html** along with **texturization** or  whatever else you need, what have you, on output.
>   There may be use cases for  running
>   kses on display. We do it in some
>   instances. But as long as the data  is
>   safe going in, it's going to be safe coming out. (And if it isn't, then 
>   you have a larger problem.)

Still want more? ;)
[The Code Cave: WordPress Security – a plugin done right](http://thecodecave.com/2010/06/22/wordpress-security-a-plugin-done-right/)
[Smashing Magazine: Keeping Web Users Safe By Sanitizing Input Data](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/11/keeping-web-users-safe-by-sanitizing-input-data/)

*Have a nice and secure day.*